# how can i use mustache template inside of singel page application?

Tags: jquery, html, mustache

i`ve been starting to learn mustache for a SPA project. it is a provate simple project. i`ve been coding usageMustage.html(to test my template) and sampleTemp.html and also data.json. I have been googling lots of articles. But i could not see any thing my test page....

MY TEMPLATE:

```
<script id="personTpl" type="text/template">
<h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>
<p>Blog URL: <a href="{{blogURL}}">{{blogURL}}</a></p>
</script>
```

Test PAGE:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.github.com/janl/mustache.js/master/mustache.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../src/jquery.mustache.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


$(function() {

                $.getJSON('json/data.json', function(data) {
    var template = $('#personTpl').html();
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
    $('#sampleArea').html(html);
});

});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sampleArea"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSON:

```
{
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    blogURL: "http://johnsmith.com",
    manager : {
        firstName: "Lisa",
        lastName: "Jones"
    }
    }
```

Comment: The execution code looks fine, so you probably have a problem somewhere in your configuration or environment setup. What console logs are you getting? What do your network calls show, especially the ones loading the scripts and the JSON data. As a side note, you shouldn't source Moustache (or any resource) directly from GitHub in your project--even a test project. GitHub isn't a CDN, and loading resources from there can introduce unexpected problems depending on the resource type.